# UIActivityIndicatorView não funciona

Tags: ios, objective-c

Quero exibir o indicator de **atividade** após o clique em um botão. Esse botão irá atualizar o app. Segui exemplos e a documentação, mas não funciona...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // .. snip
    indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    [self.view addSubview:indicator];
    [indicator stopAnimating];
    //indicator.hidden = TRUE;
    //[indicator setHidden:YES];
}

-(IBAction)actAtualizar:(id)sender {
    //[indicator setHidden:YES];
    //indicator.hidden = FALSE;
    [indicator startAnimating];
    //[indicator setHidden:NO];
    //[indicator stopAnimating];
    //indicator.hidden = TRUE;
    [self carregaDados];
    NSLog(@"teste de atualizacao", nil);
}


-(void)carregaDados{
    // ...     
    [indicator stopAnimating];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que quando você faz startAnimation, a interface só poderá ser atualizada de fato quando terminar uma iteração do *runloop* do IOS. O problema é que não há tempo para a animação começar, pois é postado o evento startAnimation, depois o método carregaDados é executado até o fim e depois é postado o evento para terminar a animação. Quando os eventos forem de fato ser processados você já executou seu método.

Existem algumas formas de resolver isso, a **mais recomendada** seria executar um método que demora muito em uma thread separada, para não travar a interface. Dessa forma, você pode começar a animação, disparar o carregaDados em outra *thread* e quando acabar dar o stopAnimation. Assim, a barra vai ficar animada enquanto está processando o carregaDados.

**Outra forma**, é fazer com que o carregaDados seja, com certeza, executado após o start animation. Um exemplo de como fazer isso é:

```
[indicator startAnimating];
[self performSelector:@selector(carregaDados) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.01];

...

- (void)carregaDados{
    ...
    [indicator stopAnimating];
}
```

Lembrando que não é recomendado executar um método que trave a aplicação e o usuário tenha que ficar esperando. Imagine uma tableView que ele não possa nem dar scroll porque a UI está travada.

**Referências**:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850186/iphone-uiactivityindicatorview-not-starting-or-stopping

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391343/run-an-uiactivityindicatorview-while-the-main-thread-is-busy

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317068/how-do-i-show-and-start-animating-a-uiactivityindicatorview-from-within-a-method

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:

Comment: consegui... meu objeto nao estava relacionado com o view e nao com o indicator,,,... muito lega sua resposta valew

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que percebi você criou o `ActivityIndicatorView` via código, ou seja, não adicionou o componente no `.xib`.

Neste caso você precisa definir o `frame` do seu objeto na tela:

```
//Por padrão se você NÃO definir o frame o objeto será colocado na posição: (0,0)
indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
[indicator setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, indicator.frame.size.width, indicator.frame.size.height)]; 
. . .
```

---

Caso você possua o componente adicionado no `.xib` basta comentar as seguintes linhas do seu código:

```
//Comentar as linhas abaixo
>>> indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
>>> [self.view addSubview:indicator];
. . .
```

O fato de você ter colocado o `ActivityIndicatorView` direto no `.xib` já fica definido a alocação do objeto.

Comment: no .h esta assim @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator;

Comment: iTSangar desculpa a ignorancia pois estou começando em desenvolvimento ios oque é .xib, é equivalente a oque em android

Comment: consegui... meu objeto nao estava relacionado com o view e nao com o indicator,,,... xib é usado no modo antigo jah entendi... valew